# How to click button Function and go another page at same time

Tags: javascript, html

I want click download button and go another page at same time
I'm try it many times but didn't work

```
<a onclick="yourlink()" download="" button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download </button></a>

<a id="newtest"  hidden="hidden" onclick="saveDownloadDetails();" href="{{asset($Music->Audio->filename) }}" download=""  data-uk-tooltip="title: {{ __('main.Download_Track')}}"></i></button></a>

<script>
    function yourlink(){
        var locs = [href= "{{ url('/download') }}"]

        for (let i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {                                                                
            window.open(locs[i], "_self")                                            
            document.getElementById("newtest").click();
        }
     };
</script>
```

Comment: if you have 10 urls, how would you open 10 urls same time? window can open only one right?

Comment: I got this code from the internet and I have no idea about it. All I need to do is open the following two codes at once
href = "{url ('/ download')}}"
document.getElementById ("newtest"). click ();

Comment: function yourlink(){
    window.open("{url ('/ download')}}", "_self")
    document.getElementById("newtest").click();
  };

wouldn't that work?

Comment: No. Even if both codes are entered, only one will work at a time

Comment: You need to click, than redirect... otherwise click will not work after redirection @EkaterinaZakharenkova

Comment: The download will not take place when you do as you are told. But there is an visit to the page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.